# groovy code to create database with no build id

Tags: database, grails, groovy

At present, we are supposed to provide a tenant id to create net new database for a tenant . But there is no way to create net new databases for the default tenant. Initially it was agreed to create the default tenant database with "_system" but later it got changed and there is no support to create the default tenant db.

**I need groovy code to create database with no tenant id.**

Comment: "I need groovy code to create database with no tenant id." - FYI... Grails generally isn't involved in creating the database unless you are using an in memory database.

Answer (score -1):

I understand your question now.  When you run your app, your app will create a database and with a suffix like "_100" added to the name of the database.  You don't want the suffix added anymore.

When you run a Grails app, it does not create a database for you.  You will have a database created ahead of time yourself.

If you said the app did create a database, your programmer might have a SQL script somewhere in your app.

You must have something like this in your source code .executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MyDatabaseName")

See if you can find this SQL and change it.

Comment: Oh forgot to mention.  If you change the name of the id column, the Grails Scaffolding / Binding will not work well.  It is looking for the id column that is named "id".

Comment: I want to create database with no tenant id.. like it should be 'smsthtndrrhh' not smsthtndrrhh_100. The underscore 100 should not be present

Comment: "like it should be 'smsthtndrrhh' not smsthtndrrhh_100" - Whatever tool you are using to create the database should allow you to specify whatever name you like.

Comment: Grails does not create database. You need to create and name the database yourself.  And then Grails will create the tables using the name of your domain classes automatically.  It will be easier if you can post some sample here.

Comment: I am not getting it !

Comment: It sounds like I don't understand your question.  Correct me if I am wrong. You have a Grails app. The app created a database and added a suffix to the name of your database "_100".  You don't want the suffix added to the name of your database anymore.  Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: yeh , I am using groovy grails tool suite , and it is creating a database with suffix _100 and now I want to create a database with no suffix .

Comment: " and it is creating a database with suffix _100 and now I want to create a database with no suffix" - I don't think there is anything in Grails which would be creating a database for you.  Are you sure that the database doesn't already exist with that name before you run the app?

Comment: Grails does not create database for you when you run the app.  Your guy has a SQL script that creates the database with a suffix.  You need to go over your source code to see where he/she put that SQL script and change it.

Comment: You must have something like this in your source code `.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MyDatabaseName")`

Comment: @tom6502.. yeah Thanks for the information , I have understood where to make the changes !